# How to stick dropdown arrow at one place

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors, styling

I'm trying to fix the arrow at one fixed position. Currently if the dropdown options gets increased then the arrow gets displaced as you can see in the [codesandbox](https://codepen.io/khamran1/pen/MWmpRZj?editors=1100) and in the example below. To regenerate add the options in the service dropdown to see the arrow/beak gets displaced.

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
}

.list .item {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list .item:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.list .item.item-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.list .item.item-dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.list .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: -20px;
}

.list .dd-menu {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.list .dd-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  margin-left: -8px;
  top: 45%;
  left: -4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Home</div>
  <div class="item">About</div>
  <div class="item item-dropdown">Services
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="dd-menu">
        <div class="item">Cleaning</div>
        <div class="item">Dry</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You pixels instead of percentage when positioning the arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you used `bottom` property to align `.dropdown-content`, use `bottom` property on the `.dd-menu:before` to align it at place i.e. adjacent to 'Services'.

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
}

.list .item {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list .item:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.list .item.item-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.list .item.item-dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.list .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: -20px;
}

.list .dd-menu {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.list .dd-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  margin-left: -8px;
  bottom: 24px;
  left: -4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Home</div>
  <div class="item">About</div>
  <div class="item item-dropdown">Services
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="dd-menu">
        <div class="item">Cleaning</div>
        <div class="item">Dry</div>
        <div class="item">Ironing</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```